# Calculating eucledian distance inside reactive dataframe in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do some transformation to the reactive `dataframe` in `shiny`. I want to use the function `euc.dist` to the reactive dataframe `bathy_new()` in the code below.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidRow(
  numericInput(inputId = "n", "Group ", value = 1), 
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  bathy <- structure(list(`Corrected Time` = structure(c(
    1512040500, 1512040500,
    1512040501, 1512040502, 1512040502, 1512040503
  ), class = c(
    "POSIXct",
    "POSIXt"
  ), tzone = "UTC"), Longitude = c(
    -87.169858, -87.169858,
    -87.1698618, -87.1698652, -87.1698652, -87.16986785
  ), Latitude = c(
    33.7578743,
    33.7578743, 33.75788237, 33.75789018, 33.75789018, 33.75789717
  ), `Depth (m)` = c(
    3.95096, 3.82296, 3.63096, 3.57096, 3.48096,
    3.32096
  ), easting = c(
    484269.60819222, 484269.60819222, 484269.257751374,
    484268.944306767, 484268.944306767, 484268.700169299
  ), northing = c(
    3735323.04565401,
    3735323.04565401, 3735323.94098565, 3735324.80742908, 3735324.80742908,
    3735325.58284154
  ), diff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(
    1, 1,
    1, 2, 2, 2
  )), .Names = c(
    "Corrected Time", "Longitude", "Latitude",
    "Depth (m)", "easting", "northing", "diff", "group"
  ), row.names = c(
    NA,
    -6L
  ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



  euc.dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    distance <- sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
    return(distance)
  }
  # 
  bathy_new <- reactive({
    bathy %>% dplyr::filter(group == input$n)
  })

  test <- bathy_new() 

  dist <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    dist <- euc.dist(x1 = test[i, "easting"] %>% .$easting,
                     y1 = test[i, "northing"] %>% .$northing,
                     x2 = test[i+1, 'easting'] %>% .$easting,
                     y2 = test[i+1, 'northing'] %>% .$northing)
  }
  test$dist <- dist

  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    qplot(cumsum(test$dist), bathy_new()$`Depth (m)`)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data here is very small data compared to my original set. But the goal is to find eucledian distance between points in each group. In this small dataset, I have 2 groups ; 1 and 2.

I keep getting the following error

`Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

I can run this code outside of shiny just fine but not sure how to deal with reactive data.

This is the chunk of code where there is error:

```
test <- bathy_new() 

      dist <- NULL
      for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
        dist <- euc.dist(x1 = test[i, "easting"] %>% .$easting,
                         y1 = test[i, "northing"] %>% .$northing,
                         x2 = test[i+1, 'easting'] %>% .$easting,
                         y2 = test[i+1, 'northing'] %>% .$northing)
      }
      test$dist <- dist
```

Eventually, I want to plot cumulative distance `cum(dist)` and depth `Depth (m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because you actually tried to assign a `reactive` to the variable `test`. This can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.

So what you need to do is to place that code inside of a reactive expression, such as `renderPlot`.

```
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    test <- bathy_new() 

    dist <- NULL
    for (i in 1:(nrow(test) - 1)){
      dist <- euc.dist(x1 = test[i, "easting"] %>% .$easting,
                       y1 = test[i, "northing"] %>% .$northing,
                       x2 = test[i+1, 'easting'] %>% .$easting,
                       y2 = test[i+1, 'northing'] %>% .$northing)
    }

    test$dist <- dist
    qplot(cumsum(test$dist), bathy_new()$`Depth (m)`)
  })
```

This should get rid of the error, however I think you may have some trouble with your `for` loop as well. You iterate through `1:nrow(test)` but you calculate with `i+1` inside the loop. Because of this dist is going to be `NA` and thus your plot will not show anything.

I modified your loop to iterate through `1:(nrow(test) - 1)` in order to get valid results.

I would also like to point out the way `Shiny` works. Shiny runs code outside of the server function **once per R process**, then runs code inside the server function **once per connection**. And then there are reactives which run **every time their dependency changes**.

See [this topic](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/231874748-Scaling-and-Performance-Tuning-in-RStudio-Connect) for more help

So it is better to define data and functions outside of the `server` function, since they only need to run once. If they are inside the `server` function they are ran every single time a new user is connected to the app which works but it is not efficient.

**Full code**:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

bathy <- structure(list(`Corrected Time` = structure(c(
  1512040500, 1512040500,
  1512040501, 1512040502, 1512040502, 1512040503
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Longitude = c(
  -87.169858, -87.169858,
  -87.1698618, -87.1698652, -87.1698652, -87.16986785
), Latitude = c(
  33.7578743,
  33.7578743, 33.75788237, 33.75789018, 33.75789018, 33.75789717
), `Depth (m)` = c(
  3.95096, 3.82296, 3.63096, 3.57096, 3.48096,
  3.32096
), easting = c(
  484269.60819222, 484269.60819222, 484269.257751374,
  484268.944306767, 484268.944306767, 484268.700169299
), northing = c(
  3735323.04565401,
  3735323.04565401, 3735323.94098565, 3735324.80742908, 3735324.80742908,
  3735325.58284154
), diff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(
  1, 1,
  1, 2, 2, 2
)), .Names = c(
  "Corrected Time", "Longitude", "Latitude",
  "Depth (m)", "easting", "northing", "diff", "group"
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

euc.dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  distance <- sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
  return(distance)
}

ui <- fluidRow(
  numericInput(inputId = "n", "Group ", value = 1), 
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  bathy_new <- reactive({
    bathy %>% dplyr::filter(group == input$n)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    test <- bathy_new() 

    dist <- NULL
    for (i in 1:(nrow(test) - 1)){
      dist <- euc.dist(x1 = test[i, "easting"] %>% .$easting,
                       y1 = test[i, "northing"] %>% .$northing,
                       x2 = test[i+1, 'easting'] %>% .$easting,
                       y2 = test[i+1, 'northing'] %>% .$northing)
    }

    test$dist <- dist
    qplot(cumsum(test$dist), bathy_new()$`Depth (m)`)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @GyD thank you so much for explaining how to deal with class reaactive. Didn't realize that I would have to put everything inside the renderPlot function. Also thanks for pointing out about the problem with the for loop. I had used shiny in past but it's been a while. The code works perfect.